# Hugepages not utilized by MySQL 5.0, CentOS 5

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

I've set up Hugepages, but i'm not seeing any of them reserved.
Have I missed a step, or for some particular reason, is MySQL is unable to utilize the Hugepages?  I have not created a mount of hugetlbfs, although from what I read, MySQL would not call pages in such a manner.  If I'm wrong, please let me know, as that would be a trivial solution.  Almost all my MySQL tables are using InnoDB.

NOTE: I created a hugetlbfs, no change as expected.  Is it possible that rebooting would rectify this situation? I would not want to go through the procedure, as this is high availability, but would do so if necessary.

This is the configurations, which I believe are relevant.

#### `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
...
## Huge Pages
vm.nr_hugepages = 4096
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 27

## SHM
kernel.shmmax = 34359738368
kernel.shmall = 8589934592
...
```

#### `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
...
mysql             soft    nofile          12888
mysql             hard    nofile          51552
@mysql            soft    memlock         unlimited
@mysql            hard    memlock         unlimited
```

#### `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
large-pages
...
```

#### `grep Huge /proc/meminfo`

```
HugePages_Total:  4096
HugePages_Free:   4096
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

#### `id mysql`

```
uid=27(mysql) gid=27(mysql) groups=27(mysql) context=root:system_r:unconfined_t:SystemLow-SystemHigh
```

#### `tail -6 /var/log/mysqld.log`

```
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 1342193664 bytes. errno 12
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
120808 15:49:25  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1729804158
120808 15:49:25 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.95'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

I would really appreciate any help, I'm completely out of ideas.  If I missed any more relevant configs, or diagnostics, please comment and I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you edit /etc/init.d/mysqld, add following under `prog="MySQL"` restart mysql and see if the issue persists?

> ulimit -l unlimited

I suspect you are hitting following bug.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=565534

Comment: Thank you for providing that bug report link, it explains my situation exactly.  I've finally got Hugepages working!!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you add this line

```
ulimit -l unlimited
```

after the line 'prog="MySQL"' in /etc/init.d/mysqld start up script and restarting the service.

This is a bug in CentOS 5 and should be fixed in Centos 6.

Please confirm whether this works for you.